# How to change python version used by python-green

Tags: python-green

I have both Python 2.7 and 3.3 installed in my box. How would I change `python-green` configuration to use one or the other without changing /usr/bin/python symbolic link?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `venv`. This creates a virtual environment where all scripts use a particular python version by default.

```
pip install virtualenv
virutalenv -p <PATH_TO_PYTHON_3> <VENV_PATH>
source <VENV_PATH>/Scripts/activate
```

Once you activate `venv`,

```
install green
green <MODULE_TO_TEST>
```

To stop using this environment,

```
deactivate
```

Most packages, even the ones which support multiple Python versions, don't have run-time switches. So, you need to install green *after* you activate venv. Otherwise, the currently active (in your case, global) python version - lets assume 2.7 - calls its globally installed `pip`, which would install green for Python 2.7.

Answer (score 1):

`green` can now be run directly as a module. To do this, use `/path/to/python -m green`

Answer (score 0):

Using `venv` as Sharadh suggests is absolutely the best way to go about this.

Having said that, it can be useful to know that green actually installs three application binaries:

```
green
greenX
greenX.Y
```

Where `X` is the major version of python (2 or 3) and Y is the minor version of python.  So lets say you install green under the "system" installation of Python 3.3 and then 3.4.  The following would occur:

```
green    <- Points to green in 3.3
green3   <- Points to green in 3.3
green3.3 <- Points to green in 3.3
green    <- Overwrites the previous green, now points to 3.4
green3   <- Overwrites the previous green3, now points to 3.4
green3.4 <- Points to green in 3.4
```

So, in summary:

1. Use `venv` -- it's much more sane.
2. If you *must* use multiple "system" python versions, use `greenX.Y` in all your commands, and you'll always get the correct one.